# How To Assign Different YoungsModulus To A Multi-material Mesh?

Tags: finite-element-method

I have a mesh designed in Blender and I am using SOFA Physics engine simulator (based on FEM), however, I don't know how to assign different YoungModulus to a mesh like mine since each parts are interwined. It would be easier if I have two separate meshes e.g. encapsulation.

Do anyone has any idea how to assign different E for a multi-material mesh?

[image]

Comment: Define X horizontal wires with an E and Y horizontal with different E then specify joins...

Comment: I dont understand you, do you have an example I can see in detail.

Comment: No, I don’t have an example or one already done. I was offering an idea to help you think through your problem.

Comment: Thanks! but this not true at all in Blender that's why I am asking how to do that specifically in blender, it seems there is no feature even for young Modulus in Blender and I wonder how to do that

Comment: Since this is in Blender, I will assume that complex details like specifying different moduli are not supported.

Comment: BTW, I found the solution in freecad, you can assign different youngmodulus easily to the mesh